# How can i get HTML Formated text in this popup box Like: <li> _ _ _ _</li> <br> <h1> _ _ _ _</h1>etc

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

at this time When text select, The popup show all selected text as in simple format, Like one paragraph. But i want that, the popup should use complete html tag when showing selected text. Like

```
<li> _ _ _ _</li> <br> <h1> _ _ _ _</h1>etc...
```

see my code:

```js
const container = document.querySelector('.storypara');
const popupContainer = document.querySelector('.popupContainer');

container.addEventListener('mouseup', (e) => {
  const selectedText = window.getSelection().toString();
  if (selectedText) {
    showPopup(selectedText);
  }
});

popupContainer.addEventListener('click', (event) => {
  if (event.target.matches('.popupContainer')) {
    popupContainer.classList.remove('show');
  }
});

function showPopup(selectedText) {

  // set the selected text as html inside popup element
  document.querySelector('.popup').innerHTML = selectedText;
  popupContainer.classList.add('show');

}
```

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
}


.popupContainer {
  position: fixed;
  width: 100vw;
  height: 100vh;
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.7);
  top: 0;
  display: none;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  color: red;


}

.show {
  display: flex;
}

.popup {
  background: #fff;
  padding: 10px;
  border-radius: 3px;
  box-shadow: 0 0 5px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
  width: 80%;
}
```

```html
<div class="storypara">
<p><strong>A Bold example Line</strong><br>
Here are some examples of paragraphs. Here are some examples of paragraphs. Here are some examples of paragraphs. Here are some examples of paragraphs. Here are some examples of paragraphs. </p>

<h2>An Unordered HTML List</h2>

<ul>
  <li>Coffee</li>
  <li>Tea</li>
  <li>Milk</li>
</ul>  

<h2>An Ordered HTML List</h2>

<ol>
  <li>Coffee</li>
  <li>Tea</li>
  <li>Milk</li>
</ol> 
  <p>Here are some examples of paragraphs. Here are some examples of paragraphs. Here are some examples of paragraphs. Here are some examples of paragraphs. Here are some examples of paragraphs. Here are some examples of paragraphs. </p>
</div>


<div class="popupContainer">
  <div class="popup"></div>
</div>
```

How can i get this plz help me. my main purpose
at this time When text select, The popup show all selected text as in simple format, Like one paragraph. But i want that, the popup should use complete html tag when showing selected text. Like

```
<li> _ _ _ _</li> <br> <h1> _ _ _ _</h1>etc...
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: The _title_ of this question needs rephrasing. Please stick to plain English (no code) and try to present your issue in a general way. For example: "How can I get user selection as rich-HTML and not just plain text?"

Comment: Also, I'm afraid you're going to need something a bit more convoluted than ```getSelection```. It occurs to me that _maybe_ detecting which DOM node contains selection start and end would work, and then traversing the DOM tree to get all elements within those. Lots of caveats down that road, though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, not quite what you want, but a lot closer to what you are asking for. Here it goes:

Update your script to be as follows:

```
  <script>
  const container = document.querySelector('.storypara');
  const popupContainer = document.querySelector('.popupContainer');

  // this method is added
  // It gives the text of HTML of selected text :)
  function getHTMLOfSelection () {
      var range;
      if (document.selection && document.selection.createRange) {
        range = document.selection.createRange();
        return range.htmlText;
      }
      else if (window.getSelection) {
        var selection = window.getSelection();
        if (selection.rangeCount > 0) {
          range = selection.getRangeAt(0);
          var clonedSelection = range.cloneContents();
          var div = document.createElement('div');
          div.appendChild(clonedSelection);
          return div.innerHTML;
        }
        else {
          return '';
        }
      }
      else {
        return '';
      }
    }


  container.addEventListener('mouseup', (e) => {
    const selectedText = getHTMLOfSelection(); // First get the raw HTML text
    if (selectedText) {
      //selectedText.split("<").join("&lt");    // Now replacing the < so that browser don't render it
      //selectedText.split(">").join("&gt");   // Also replacing the > so that browser don't render it
      //console.log(selectedText);
      showPopup(selectedText); // using the 'xmp' tags around the text, to show the html as it is 
    }
  });

  popupContainer.addEventListener('click', (event) => {
    if (event.target.matches('.popupContainer')) {
      popupContainer.classList.remove('show');
    }
  });

  function showPopup(selectedText) {

    // set the selected text as html inside popup element
    document.querySelector('.popup').innerHTML = selectedText;
    popupContainer.classList.add('show');

  }
</script>
```

I've added a function, which gives you the HTML of the selected text.
This is all you can do to show the HTML to the user. Hope it helps.

Let me know please if it don't work at your end :) Will be happy to help

Comment: Thanks for your hard work, Lots of Love for that, But as you made this script that showing html format of selected text Right ?
But i want the HTML output of selection in popup box, Like

```
<strong>example Line</strong>
```
example Line must be show bold in Popup, not with HTML <strong> Tag
i think now you are understanding.
Thanks in advance, Plz help me to make solve it

Comment: @RakeshSuthar I have edited the answer. See if this is what you are asking for :) If not, let me know. If yes, don't forget to mark it as right answer ;)

Comment: Happy to help :)